# Ошибка с Asyncio. Task was destroyed but it is pending!

Tags: python-3.x, сокет, python-3.6, asyncio, discord-api

При написании кода на `Python 3.6.1` с библиотекой `asyncio` возникла ошибка:

> RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
>
> Task was destroyed but it is pending!
>
> task: \Fores\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:304> wait_for=Future pending cb=[TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x060B5BD0>()]
>
> Unclosed client session client_session:  aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x06079C10

Сама ошибка возникала при отправке с клиента трёх пакетов несколько раз подряд.
В общем, вот пакеты для вызова ошибки:

`remove_messages
417740672368640001
10`

Серверная часть:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from socket import *
Client = discord.Client()
bot_prefix = "!"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

async def remove(data_channel, data_text):
    mgs = []
    async for x in client.logs_from(discord.Object(id=data_channel), limit=data_text):
        mgs.append(x)
    await client.delete_messages(mgs)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 21111
    BUFSIZ = 1024
    ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
    tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
    tcpSerSock.listen(5)
    while True:
        tcpCliSock, addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
        while True:
            data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
            if data.decode('utf8').find("remove_messages") != -1:
                data_channel = ()
                while not data_channel:
                    data_channel = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
                data_text = ()
                while not data_text:
                    data_text = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
                data_channel = data_channel.decode('utf-8')
                data_text = data_text.decode('utf-8')
                data_text = int(data_text)
                await remove(data_channel, data_text)
client_token = "NDE3MzQ4MjMyNDQ4OTY2NjY2.DZsgEw.87bhFRAFteARX9G0TgGMdNldUeQ"
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(client.run(client_token))
```

Клиентская часть:

```
from socket import *
import time
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 21111
BUFSIZ = 1024
data = "remove_messages"
data_2 = "417740672368640001"
data_3 = "10"
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)
while True:
    tcpCliSock.send(data.encode())
    time.sleep(15)
    tcpCliSock.send(data_2.encode())
    time.sleep(10)
    tcpCliSock.send(data_3.encode())
    time.sleep(3)
```

Заранее большое спасибо

Comment: @jfs Укоротил по максимуму и сделал все условия для вызова ошибки. Запускать сначала серверную часть, затем клиентскую

Comment: у вас смешано блокирующее API для сокетов (которое само по себе неправильно используется) и async. Используйте либо либо другое¶ Начните с рабочего примера из вводного руководства какого-нибудь и изменяйте его для своих нужд пошагово, пока не сломаете.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем, кому был интересен ответ на вопрос.
В библиотеке `asyncio` была найдена команда `asyncio.start_server(server_coro)`, через которую была решена проблема.